# Can't use --help with printf

Tags: command-line, bash

Most programs print usage and quit with "--help". But I can't get it to work with `printf`:

```bash
$ printf --help
bash: printf: --: invalid option
printf: usage: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
```

`man 1 printf` says:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> **printf** FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
>
> **printf** OPTION
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> Print ARGUMENT(s) according to FORMAT, or execute according to OPTION:
>
> **--help** display this help and exit

There's also nothing wrong about the [coreutils source code](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/printf.c):

```c
  /* We directly parse options, rather than use parse_long_options, in
     order to avoid accepting abbreviations.  */
  if (argc == 2)
    {
      if (STREQ (argv[1], "--help"))
        usage (EXIT_SUCCESS);

      if (STREQ (argv[1], "--version"))
        {
          version_etc (stdout, PROGRAM_NAME, PACKAGE_NAME, Version, AUTHORS,
                       (char *) NULL);
          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    }
```

Why can't I do `printf --help`?

Answer (score 2):

There's two types of `printf`. The one provided by coreutils and the one provided by Bash as a shell built-in.

```
$ type printf
printf is a shell builtin
$ /usr/bin/printf --help
Usage: /usr/bin/printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
  or:  /usr/bin/printf OPTION
Print ARGUMENT(s) according to FORMAT, or execute according to OPTION:
...
```

In order to get help about Bash's built-in, use the `help` command instead:

```
$ help printf
printf: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
    Formats and prints ARGUMENTS under control of the FORMAT.
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two printfs available to you: the shell builtin and an executable.  The shell builtin is described in `man bash`.  It does not support `--help`.  You can, however, get information about it with `help printf`.

`man 1 printf` describes `/usr/bin/printf` and it does, in fact support `--help`:

```
$ /usr/bin/printf --help
Usage: /usr/bin/printf FORMAT [ARGUMENT]...
  or:  /usr/bin/printf OPTION
Print ARGUMENT(s) according to FORMAT, or execute according to OPTION:

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

FORMAT controls the output as in C printf.  Interpreted sequences are:

  \"      double quote
  \\      backslash
  \a      alert (BEL)
  \b      backspace
  \c      produce no further output
  \e      escape
  \f      form feed
  \n      new line
  \r      carriage return
  \t      horizontal tab
  \v      vertical tab
  \NNN    byte with octal value NNN (1 to 3 digits)
  \xHH    byte with hexadecimal value HH (1 to 2 digits)
  \uHHHH  Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character with hex value HHHH (4 digits)
  \UHHHHHHHH  Unicode character with hex value HHHHHHHH (8 digits)
  %%      a single %
  %b      ARGUMENT as a string with '\' escapes interpreted,
          except that octal escapes are of the form \0 or \0NNN

and all C format specifications ending with one of diouxXfeEgGcs, with
ARGUMENTs converted to proper type first.  Variable widths are handled.

NOTE: your shell may have its own version of printf, which usually supersedes
the version described here.  Please refer to your shell's documentation
for details about the options it supports.

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/printf>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) printf invocation'
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf` is a shell (`bash`) built-in too. So when you run

```
printf --help
```

the built-in `printf` is executed because by default the built-in ones always get precedence over the external ones and it doesn't have `--help` option, hence the error.

To find all the available `printf` executables:

```
type -a printf
```

It will show the executables in the order of precedence.

You can check the `help` page of built-in `printf` by:

```
help printf
```

On the other hand if you want to run the external `printf`, do any one of the following:

```
command printf
"printf"
'printf'
\printf
```